# How to Fetch results from server using JQuery AJAX? on the basis of Drop-down Condition

Tags: ajax, php-7, dropdown-options

I have two conditions, if two conditions are matching the given value should  display. I am using input value as Drop down. If the value of two drop-downs matched i need to display my value on same page.
For Example:
dropDown1 selection -> KM : **10(Dropdown)**, 
dropDown1 selection -> Fueal : **2 Lit(Dropdown)**

Output: **Happy Jorney**
On the same page and below the drop-down List.

Comment: if you need a condition within ajax functionality (or) before ajax functionality

Comment: @divyasekar If two drop-down select and if it is matching the value should be display below like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9pA.png

Comment: You are are confusing using word Ajax. its on page JS give me few minutes I will let you know.

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Let me explain, i need the the value should be display without click or refresh the page, so that i need AJAX,

Comment: ok now its second part after selection from where you will get result ? on the basis of two matched sections.

Comment: yes, here my basic workout : https://paste.ofcode.org/Cu6SEKFMm6SGu8e4PiAM62, if i am wrong pls correct me.    Here if i select I have "One" & I want "two" the value should be display like 20$, my op->https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9pA.png

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Any better suggestions, happy to learn.

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad small corrections in above code this the final : https://paste.ofcode.org/3a9yDZcajfvfVVJEs4VhJ7U

Comment: though its not magento related question but as we start discussion so wait few minutes

Comment: FYI => The output is https://snag.gy/XdKFbV.jpg (almost working) but the filter reset once it return the value, i need the dropdown value stay what customer choose dont reset, so that customer try multiple combination.

Comment: @zus chek below answer & let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92177/discussion-between-hassan-ali-shahzad-and-zus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have two files basically, look the code your will get clear understanding for request flow also it will not change user selction:

your html file will be testing.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Upgrade Cost</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form method='POST' action='home.php'>

Name : <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
Email Id : <input type="text" name="email_id"/><br/><br/>
Contact Number : <input type="text" name="contact_number"/><br/><br/>
I have :
<select id="old">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select><br/><br/>
I want :
<select id="new">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select>
</form>
<!-- <button id="btn_check_value">Check for value</button> -->
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#new').on('change',function(){

var old_val = $("#old option:selected").val();
var new_val = $("#new option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "home.php",
dataType: "text",
data: { old: old_val, new: new_val },
success: function(data) {
    // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
    //console.log(data);
    $('#result').html(data);
}
});

});
});

</script>
</html>
```

you ajax file will be:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
$old = $_POST['old'];
$new = $_POST['new'];
if($old=='one'&&$new=='two'){

// echo json_encode(array('Cost 10$'));
echo "Upgrade Code : 10$";
}

elseif($old=='one'&&$new=='three')
{
echo "Upgrade Code : 20$";
}

elseif($old=='one'&&$new=='four')
{
echo "Upgrade Code : 30$";
}


elseif($old=='one'&&$new=='five')
{
echo "Upgrade Code : 40$";
}
else{
echo "Choose Valid Options";;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92887/room-for-zus-and-hassan-ali-shahzad @Hassan Ali Shahzad